# Compute the kernel of a quotient of a homomorphism between polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

In the ring $R_1={\mathbb Q}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$, consider the principal ideal $I_1$ generated by $g_1=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-1$, and in the ring $R_2={\mathbb Q}[s,w]$, consider the principal ideal $I_2$ generated by $g_2=s^2+18w^2-3$. Next, define a map $f:R_1 \to R_2$ by

$$
f(P(x_1,x_2,x_3))=P\bigg(\frac{s}{3}+w,\frac{s}{3}+w,\frac{s}{3}-2w\bigg)
$$

Since $f(g_1)=\frac{g_2}{3}$, we see that $f$ factors to a quotient map $f^{\sim}:\frac{R_1}{I_1} \to \frac{R_2}{I_2}$.

**Question:** What is the kernel of $f^{\sim}$ ?

My gut feeling is that there should be a simple, systematic algorithm to compute a finite set of polynomials $Q_1,\ldots,Q_k$ in $R_1$ such that the kernel of $f^{\sim}$ is generated by $p(Q_1),\ldots,p(Q_k)$, where $p$ is the canonical epimorphism $R_1\to\frac{R_1}{I_1}$, but I don't know enough computational algebraic geometry to proceed.